# Vendor specific hardware in KVM hypervisor

Tags: debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

We use `KVM` hypervisor on Debian Linux (current stable) on Fujitsu server.

Is it possible to configure `KVM` in way that it mimicks normal Fujitsu hardware? We have some software that is Fujitsu only and we would like to run it on server but in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

KVM is only a hypervisor. What you really want is for qemu to emulate specific hardware, which I doubt is possible. What you can do it pass some of the devices through to the VM, which is possible.

Comment: Well, all we would like to do is to set KVM so that installed software will detect Fujitsu server and continue installation.

Comment: it would depend on how the software detects fujitsu hardware. if it's from `dmidecode` then there might be something faked at the emulated bios level, though I suppose you'd need a special build of kvm-qemu (or rather an altered seaBIOS firmware) for that.

Comment: If it's only detecting it at installation, you might try to install on a physical server then use some kind of physical to virtual converter to create the virtual machine. As long as it isn't violating a license agreement, that is.